# Inno Setup copy OutputBaseFileName in PostCompile section

Tags: inno-setup

I want copy `OutputBaseFileName` to archive after Inno Setup Studio script compiling is finished.

I prepared this script but it doesn't work.

```
[PostCompile]
Name: CopyFile({#OutputBaseFilename}, '\\Bckserver\Source\'{#OutputBaseFilename});
```

Answer (score 3):

I will guess that you want to have the compiler copy the generated installer to yet another directory (`\\Bckserver\Source`).

---

This works:

```
Name: "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"; Parameters: "/c copy C:\path\setup.exe \\Bckserver\Source"
```

I do not think there's better solution, as Inno Setup Studio does not support preprocessor in the `PostCompile` section, so you cannot refer to `OutputBaseFilename` or system directory other than by hard-coding them.