# Inno Setup - Post Compile Batch files with variable as parameter - Parameter not converted into value of variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, inno-setup

I have an setup script to generate the setup, this works fine.
Now I created a PowerShell script, that takes 2 parameters, "program" - name of the program and "version", version of the program. The PowerShell script just copies the files somewhere based on the version.

In Inno Setup Studio I try to run the PowerShell script after the compile in the `[PostCompile]` section with following line:

```
[PostCompile]    
Name: "copysetups.cmd"; Parameters: "Program {#AppVers} "; Flags: cmdprompt redirectoutput
```

The batch file is called but the variable is not replaced with its value following output is shown in the messages window of Inno Script Studio:

```
powershell.exe .\copySetups.ps1 -program Program -version {#AppVer}
```

---

I also tried doing it via "`code:` like this:

```
[PostCompile]
Name: "copysetups.cmd"; Parameters: "Program ""{code:GetAppVersion}"""; Flags: cmdprompt redirectoutput
```

The function:

```pascal
function GetAppVersion( Param: String ): String;
begin
  Result := '{#AppVer}';
end;
```

But this doesn't work either, output is again not with the value from the function.

```
powershell.exe .\copySetups.ps1 -program Program -version {code:GetAppVersion}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inno Setup Studio does not support preprocessor in the `[PostCompile]` section. See also [Inno Setup copy OutputBaseFileName in PostCompile section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33437375/850848).

And there's no way `{code:...}` can work either, as constants (as well as any Pascal Script code) are evaluated on run time only.

---

Why don't you make the PowerShell script read the version from the compiled .exe?

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("mysetup.exe").ProductVersion
```